# Randomise selection from 2D Array

Tags: javascript, java, android, arrays, android-studio

I'm trying to create a basic quiz app in Android Studio, but I'm still fairly new to this and not sure what terms to use to search for a solution. Hopefully someone here can help.

The user can select from a series of topics, items, or a combination of both, to define their quiz. 
Once they've finished their selection it gets randomized and their quiz begins.

Topics and items are related, but not explicitly connected. For example, the user could select only one topic row, which would provide each item related to that topic. Or they could select a a single column of items, which would provide each topic related to that item.

My assumption is that this has to be achieved with a 2D array in XML, [like this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4iPY.png) With green cells being the items selected, and red cells those that weren't selected. Then operate the array in java.

I know how to create a 2D array, but I don't have enough experience to be certain that's the right decision. I'm also not sure how to operate it. Should I take the user's selection and use that to create a new array? Or can I keep the original array, randomise the numbers and skip those that weren't selected?

If anyone can point me in the right direction, or suggest a better solution, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From your image it seems like topics and items are connected, which makes sense. If this is the case, using some type of list structure alone might be more simple to visualize and work with, where each list is a topic and the items for each topic are contained in the list. If you must have a 2-d structure, maybe something like  **List<List<String>> listOfList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();**?

Comment: Topics and items are related, but not explicitly connected. For example, the user could select only one topic row, which would provide each item related to that topic. Or they could select a a single column of items, which would provide each topic related to that item.

Answer (score 0):

The code below seems like it will accomplish what you are wanting to do with the selected items in your 2-Dimensional Array of selected answers. As far as my comment suggesting to create a list of lists for this information, that may or may not be the best option as it is subjective.

Let's work with what you already have in mind (since you say you already know how to create a 2D Array for the items being selected), but then let's convert your array to an ArrayList because I do feel they offer a better structure to work with.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

String[][] twoDimentionalArrayOfEverything = { 
        {"item1", "item2", "item3"}, 
        {"item4", "item5", "item6"}, 
        {"item7", "item8", "item9"} };

ArrayList<String> selectedItemsForQuiz = 
   Arrays.stream(twoDimentionalArrayOfEverything)
    .flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a))
    //filter selected items
    .filter(b->b.equals("item1") || b.equals("item9") )
    //now turn to a collection
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<String>()));

    //loop the list
    selectedItemsForQuiz.forEach(System.out::println);  //item1 and item9
```

and here is a version using Integer values instead of strings

```
Integer[][] answerNumbers = { 
            {1, 2, 3}, 
            {4, 5, 6}, 
            {7, 8, 9} };

ArrayList<Integer> selectedItemsNumber = Arrays.stream(answerNumbers)
       .flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a))
        //filter selected items
        .filter(b->b.equals(1) || b.equals(9) )
        //now turn to a collection
       .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>()));

selectedItemsNumber.forEach(System.out::println);  //1 and 9
```

And then after all of that, since you stated you wanted to randomize the selection, shuffling should work from Java Collections:

```
Collections.shuffle(selectedItemsForQuiz);  //Strings
Collections.shuffle(selectedItemsNumber);  //Integers
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do all of that. There's quite a few methods in there I'm not familiar with, so I'll spend some time wrapping my head around them before confirming the answer.

Comment: Now worries @Samm...Basically all I have done is use streams and lambdas (Java 8) to simplify the conversion between the 2-dimensional array into an ArrayList of randomized selected answers. With the ArrayList created, all you do is build your quiz using the items collected within the list. -Everything I have done with lambdas and streams can be accomplished using loops, but I feel the code is easier to read and less complex without loops

Comment: I looked into lambda, and that's something new for me to learn. Over the last week I've become less certain that I need to store my data in a 2D Array. What I actually need is to conceptualise the data that way to keep it organised. At the moment I'm using a spreadsheet to input my data, then I'm converting that spreadsheet to JSON. At the moment I'm trying to work out how I can use JSON to get the effect I want.

Comment: If you are using Android (or actually using almost any language), SQLite is an easy database to learn/implement. Then you do not have to worry about parsing data as much between various file types/data structures, you store it in the database and then use the data whenever you need it: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: SQLite was absolutely the right decision. It took me a little while to wrap my head around it, but it's exactly what I wanted. Thanks again for your help.